# Joining data from two columns into one changes date format

Tags: r, datetime

In a dataframe, two columns (fech_A and fech_B) contains dates of death for diferent causes.

```
   fech_A  fech_B  
1 8-02-06    <NA>  
2    <NA> 8-11-18  
3 9-03-14    <NA>  
4 9-03-05    <NA>  
5    <NA> 9-08-11
```

I want to combine the dates not-NA into a new column, fech_C. With the answer in a  previously published comment, my code is

```
fech_A <- as.Date(c("8-02-06",NA,"9-03-14","9-03-05",NA),format="%d/%m/%Y")
fech_B <- as.Date(c(NA,"8-11-18",NA,NA,"9-08-11"),format="%d/%m/%Y")
calend1 <- data_frame(fech_A,fech_B)
fech_C <- with(calend1,ifelse(is.na(fech_A),fech_A,fech_B)
```

But the new column appears in a numeric format:

```
[1] -716570 -716284 -716168 -716177 -716018
```

How do I have to format data in the new column to appear as dates?

Comment: You have calend and calend1   Are they the same?  Is this a typo? Also your fech_C statement is missing a `)`

Comment: To start, your `format=` arguments are wrong. They should be `,format="%d-%m-%y"`. You need `-` because that's the separator you're using (not `/`) and you need `%y` (lowecase) because you have 2-digit years

Comment: Sorry, G5W. I have corrected the typo, called instead of calend1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a row-wise apply. I've rewritten your example to fix the errors:

```
fech_A <- as.Date(c("8-02-06",NA,"9-03-14","9-03-05",NA),format="%d-%m-%y")
fech_B <- as.Date(c(NA,"8-11-18",NA,NA,"9-08-11"),format="%d-%m-%y")
calend1 <- data_frame(fech_A,fech_B)

apply(calend1, 1, function(x) if (is.na(x['fech_A'])) {
    x['fech_B']
} else {
    x['fech_A']
})

[1] "2006-02-08" "2018-11-08" "2014-03-09" "2005-03-09" "2011-08-09"
```

I'm sure there's a better way to merge the columns together, but this works cleanly in base R and `apply` respects the data types of your dates.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the problem lies with the if else, which is generalising the date output to an integer (because the date is actually stored as an integer value, and the NAs are NA_integer_s.

The solution I use to get around this is to use the dplyr package, and use dplyr::if_else instead. The difference between them is that dplyr::if_else insists that the true and false values are of the same type, and therefore if a and b are definitely dates then it can safely assume the output is a date too.

I suspect you can force type the output with as.Date() around the if else but haven't had the need to try things like that since using the dplyr option (which is a natural fit for me as I use the tidy verse for much of the data wrangling).

Comment: Thanks. Your advice provides some ideas to an elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `coalesce`

```
library(tidyverse)
calend1 %>% 
   transmute(new = coalesce(!!! rlang::syms(names(.))))
# A tibble: 5 x 1
#  new       
#   <date>    
#1 2006-02-08
#2 2018-11-08
#3 2014-03-09
#4 2005-03-09
#5 2011-08-09
```